# Regex YouTube IFRAME

Tags: java, php, android, regex, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I want to publish an app for android (wordpress blog). The app displays also some YouTube videos.
I need a method to replace YouTube IFRAMES + EMBED-Codes (old embed method) with an a - tag:

```
<iframe ...


<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id"><img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/id/hqdefault.jpg" /></a>
```

The replacement: either via php (server) or via java (eclipse). I have only found some snippets...

```
/embed\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})/
```

But how could I use it? Please help me!

**EDIT:** I try to replace the following CODE:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/**ID**" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

@Stephan

```
$content = "contains <iframe... and article"
$search = '/<iframe.+?src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})"[^>]+?></iframe>/i';
$replace = '<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1"><img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/$1/hqdefault.jpg" /></a>';
$content = preg_replace($search, $replace, $content);
echo $content;
```

How could I used it? Error: Unknown modifier '/' (in PHP).

Comment: At least post a sample of what you're trying to replace.

Comment: Change the delimiters from '/' to '#' as I did in my anwser.

Comment: Thanks! The question is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
~<iframe.+?src="https?://www.youtube.com/embed/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})"[^>]+?></iframe>~i
```

**DEMO :**

> https://regex101.com/r/2mjn1r/1

Comment: No, thats not my question :( I will show the images with a link to the video. I have many posts (wordpress). In these posts are YT-IFRAMES. They could played in an android app very bad (flash...). I will replace these IFRAMES automatically with PHP (on server side) or JAVA (on client side).

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my question! How could I used it?

Comment: what if my frame looks like this
<iframe width="591" height="332" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/TgDMsyBW8Tw?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

it has ?featured=oembed in the end

Comment: @Mpa4Hu You can use something like this : `#<iframe.+?src="(http://)?www.youtube.com/embed/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})[^"]*"[^>]+?></iframe>#`

Comment: thank you for answering, it's not working, I think because I have also content inside those frames (document).. could you open a chat. it's really small

Comment: If using in PHP you'll need to escape the slashes and I'd also recommend adding `s?` after http so that you can support https videos. The result is `<iframe.+?src="https?:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})"[^>]+?><\/iframe>`

Comment: @Pete Thanks for noticing `s?`. Slashes need to be escaped if the regex delimiter is slash. If a different delimiter is used, escaping isn't mandatory anymore.